# When a class is loaded in JVM

Tags: java, classloader

I got two examples:

Example 1:

```
public class A {

}

public class B {

  public void m(A a) {

  }

}
public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            B b = new B();
            System.out.println("hello!");
    }

}
```

Compile all three classes. Remove A.class. Run main. No exception is thrown.

Example 2:

```
public class D {

}

public class E {

    public void omg(D d) {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        E e = new E();
    }


}
```

Compile the classes. Remove D.class. Run main method.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: D
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: D
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why? D is never referenced.

Comment: Excellent question! I guess looking at the output of `javap` would be a good start to know what is actually complied, to make sure the compiler didn't optimize out some calls. This probably contains the answer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2

Comment: The class isn't used but it is referenced. You are using it as a method argument. The class is scanned for all types it needs (basically all imports) and those will be loaded into the classloader. You can see when classes are loaded by starting the JVM with the `-verbose:class` parameter.

Comment: @M.Deinum and in the first example?

Comment: Doesn't the stacktrace say it all? The sun launcher's `.getMainMethod` looks up all method signatures. In the first example you only call that on class `C`, never on class `B`

Comment: As pointed out in the answer, the direct references are loaded eagerly and the indirect lazy (or late). Hence your B class is loaded but not verified, if you would try to invoke the method `m` it would start to fail because now Class `B` would be checked and its dependencies loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class has a reference to the class `D` within the method `public void omg(D d)`.

Normally the JVM from Sun/Oracle uses lazy resolution, so it wouldn’t matter as long as you don’t use that method, however, you can see from the stack trace that the main method is searched via the reflective operation `Class.getMethod` which makes the difference.

You can verify this with the following code:

```
public class B {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    D.main(args);
  }
}
class D {

  public void foo(E e) {}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hello world");
  }
}
class E { }
```

Here, removing `E.class` after compiling and running `java B` will not produce an error. Now insert a reflective method lookup into the code:

```
public class B {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      D.class.getMethod("main", String[].class);
    } catch(NoSuchMethodException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    D.main(args);
  }
}
class D {

  public void foo(E e) {}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hello world");
  }
}
class E { }
```

Now, removing the class `E` after compiling produces `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: E` when you run with `java B`. So the manually triggered method lookup reproduces the behavior as in your original code example though class `D` is not the `main` class here.

---

Note that you can fix the problem by removing the `public` modifier from the method `foo`. The reason is that `Class.getMethod` only considers `public` methods and skips all others.

This also applies to your original code example: removing `public` from the method `omg` will make the `NoClassDefFoundError` disappear.

Comment: very interesting example, I have tried `MethodHandles.Lookup::findStatic` instead of `Class::getMethod` to get a different result

Comment: @Eugene I think, `MethodHandles.Lookup::findStatic` works closer to what the JVM will do internally when executing an `invokestatic` instruction the first time, whereas `Class::getMethod` will trigger the initialization of a `Method[]` array holding all `public` methods of the class, if not already existing, which gets reused for subsequent searches (as well as `Class::getMethods` which will just clone that array).

Answer (score 3):

Both are allowed by JavaVM specification. In [Chapter 5. Loading, Linking, and Initializing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4) we have:

> For example, a Java Virtual Machine implementation may choose to resolve each symbolic reference in a class or interface individually when it is used ("lazy" or "late" resolution), or to resolve them all at once when the class is being verified ("eager" or "static" resolution).

My wild guess is that Sun/Oracle chose to do the "static" resolution for initial("main") class because it's likely that methods in the main class are to be invoked very soon.

Comment: Either that, or it starts resolving once the first method of the class is called.

Comment: No, the resolution behaves the same as with all other classes. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26528180/2711488)…